# nomachine cannot delete unsuccessful conn icons in recent connections

Tags: macos, nomachine

[unsuccessful conn with no remove option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbSr2.png)

[working conn with remove option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxs4c.png)
In the screenshots, they are connection icons under the Recent Connections of NoMachine Mac client. The working connection icons has 'remove connection' option when I right click, whereas the unsuccessful connection attempt icons does not have the 'remove connection' option. I have checked settings, and I did not find a way to remove the unsuccessful ones under recent connections.

How can I delete the unwanted ones from the 'recent connection panel' so that I don't have a bunch of confusing icons when I start Nomachine?

https://  www.nomachine.com/TR12K04140
I see this got closed in 2014, but I do have the latest version from the official website. I am confused. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've many NoMachine servers in my LAN, and it looks like the remove item in the context menu is missing for their icons, while I can remove connections created by me.

Open Settings dialog, then enter Privacy and check "Don't show other computers on the network".

Answer (score 1):

You can go to c:\users\youruser\documents\NoMachine and delete the nxs connections there that you don't use.